# p:input will not render value attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem rendering p:inputText from primefaces. 
Their Demo at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml is working. If I change it to my requirements it fail.

In my .xhtml I've the following code. The first part will print out the given ipaddress as plain text,

```
#{hostEntryManaged.selectedEntry.ipAddress}
```

but the value attribute of the p:inputText keeps blank. Nothing to see in the final html.

```
<h:outputLabel for="ipaddr" value="IP: " />
<p:inplace id="ipaddr" editor="true" >
    <p:inputText value="#{hostEntryManaged.selectedEntry.ipAddress}" required="true" label="text" />
</p:inplace>
```

I can add

`value="#{hostEntryManaged.selectedEntry.ipAddress}"` also to the `p:inplace`. There it works fine, till I click the field and it turns to the (desired) input field.

It feels that the `<p:inputText..../>` is out of scope, so it can't access my bean.

But there are no errors.

Comment: does the log show something ?!?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.
May be I have to update some logger Settings for Debug?

It just render the page without any values.

Comment: Have fixed it. It was a wrong `h:form` use from my side. Resolved it by reading this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054618/pajax-not-updating-pinputtext